# Compiling a smart contract without removing line breaks

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm new to write a smart contract with Ethereum.

According to an official document, compiling a smart contract needs to remove all the line-breaks in the contract's source-code :

```
var greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'
var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)
```

https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/contract_greeter.html

As I think the removing process is not *smart*, I want to compile the code itself like:

```
var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity_infile( "greeter.txt" )
# The function "solidity_infile" does not exists actually, 
# but represents what I want to do.
```

**greeter.txt**

```
contract
mortal {
    /* Define variable owner of the type address*/
    address owner;

    /* this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract */
    function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; }

    /* Function to recover the funds on the contract */
    function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); }
}

contract greeter is mortal {
    /* define variable greeting of the type string */
    string greeting;

    /* this runs when the contract is executed */
    function greeter(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    /* main function */
    function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

Does anyone how to do that?

The compiler I'm using is Solidity.

Answer (score 2):

How about loading the contract from a file into `var someContractText`  and then do the following

```
someContractText = someContractText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

Comment: How to load a file into a variable?

Comment: [loadScript](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console) . Though loadScript does not load the variables on my machine - I am trying to resolve it - probably an installation problem.